# dovecot, postfix, systemctl start never completes, mystery dependency

Tags: systemd, systemctl, xubuntu

I've installed Xubuntu 15.04 and right away I was forced to dive right into the gritty details of systemd, systemctl, systemd-analyze. Right out of the box, postfix hangs on apt-get on the configuring part. So does dovecot.

What I've learned so far is that systemd is a sophisticated service management system, capable of starting things in parallel, and with features like dependencies. I think that the reason the configuring stage, which happens at the end of an install through apt-get (but also synaptic), is that the service itself will not start, because it is waiting on a dependency.

`systemctl list-jobs` tells me dovecot is "start waiting". Start meaning, it is in a start mode. And waiting means that it is waiting on something.
Now, the problem I'm having is, what is it waiting on?

I can do things like `systemd-analyze plot`, `dot`, and all the rest of it, but none of the options or combinations have been able to tell me simply what it is waiting on. I can see all the things it depends on, but which one is it specifically not happy about? I don't have to wade through all the dependencies manually I hope?

Right now, the only way to get my system going, is to put up with the errors on startup, and then manually starting these services using `systemctl --job-mode=ignore-dependencies start dovecot postfix`.

I've googled around, and can't find any way to give me an overview that contains all the state based information, like what service depends on what, and what state each of those are in. The svg or the svg converted from dot, isn't telling me that.

Comment: For now, what I've done, is: systemctl disable dovecot postfix. And then once my system boots up, manually run this in a script: systemctl --job-mode=ignore-dependencies start dovecot postfix.

Comment: On http://unix.stackexchange.com you will get probably a more friendly treatment.

Comment: Than again on ubuntu you will not ;-) My new 15.04 install swapped the mouse keys, and I'm yet to figure it out how to unswap. Tried all the obvious stuff.